# Customize email_verified_at column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a laravel project that needs to send a verification email. I successfully send an email but when I try to verify the email by clicking "Verify email address" button in the email it shows me the error unknown column `"email_verified_at"`. I don't have rights to add or edit fields in the database. I am just wondering where can I change this field to something else? like instead of email_verified_at I'll use emailVerifiedAt

Comment: Post a sample of your code.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to add or edit fields in the database, how do you plan on storing the value for `emailVerifiedAt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have changed the `email_verified_at` column name to something
> else you can try this

By default laravel `User` model extends [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php) and this class is using a trait named [`Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php) which contains all the logic for verifying email address. So you can override the methods of trait inside `User` Model

Inside the `User.php` model

```
/**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->emailVerifiedAt);
    }

    /**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {
        return $this->forceFill([
            'emailVerifiedAt' => $this->freshTimestamp(),
        ])->save();
    }
```